# How to access hasura graphql interface?

Tags: graphql, hasura, hasura-docker

I'd like to access the graphql interface of hasura directly (without going through the hasura admin dashboard). In the admin dashboard I see the following

[image]

When I try to navigate to that url I get the following error message

```
{"errors":[{"message":"PersistedQueryNotSupported","extensions":{"path":"$","code":"not-supported"}}]}
```

[image]

I've tried clearing my browser cache and doing a hard reload but that doesn't seem to help.

I'm running `hasura/graphql-engine:v2.36.0` in docker with the following env vars

```
      HASURA_GRAPHQL_DATABASE_URL: <postgres uri>
      HASURA_GRAPHQL_ENABLE_CONSOLE: "true"
      HASURA_GRAPHQL_DEV_MODE: "true"
      HASURA_GRAPHQL_PG_CONNECTIONS: 2
```

How can I properly configure hasura so that the graphql interface is accessible on it's own without having to go through the admin dashboard?

Answer (score 0):

> Enable persisted queries using the environment variable
> HASURA_GRAPHQL_ENABLE_PERSISTED_QUERIES (--enable-persisted-queries)
> to true (default: false), and the query TTL in the cache store can be
> set using the environment variable
> HASURA_GRAPHQL_PERSISTED_QUERIES_TTL (--persisted-queries-ttl).

> This feature is available in EE version of Hasura only.

https://github.com/hasura/graphql-engine/issues/273#issuecomment-1870091054